# How to pivot table based on assigned "ID" to value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table bulked with data looking something like that after loading:

| given_id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | example_val1_col_1 |
| 2 | example_val1_col_2 |
| 3 | example_val1_col_3 |
| 1 | example_val2_col_1 |
| 2 | example_val2_col_2 |

The ID I assigned to this data reference to which column they should go next.
And what I'm trying to achieve is to pivot data to look like following:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| example_val1_col_1 | example_val1_col_2 | example_val1_col_3 |
| example_val2_col_1 | example_val2_col_2 | NULL |

What I've tried is a simple pivoting, which didn't help because of it's aggregate function that doesn't match the rows correctly.

```
select [1],[2],[3]
from
(
  select given_id, data
  from example_table

) d
pivot
(
  min(data)
  for given_idin ([1],[2],[3])
) piv;
```

How would I do it correctly?
Thank you

Comment: Your question is very problematic and more information is needed. There is no column which can be used to know which data should return in which row (unless you give us the rule) . For example, why "example_val1_col_2" is coming in the  result set in the same row as "example_val1_col_1" ?

Comment: For example Aaron added information which was not in the question `ORDER BY data` but who said that this is the order that fit you? If your rule is using the beginning of the value for example "example_val1" will be in first row in the result and "example_val2" in the second and so on, then Aaron's solution fails for the data `(1,'example_val2_col_1'),(1,'example_val1_col_1'),(2,'example_val1_col_2'),(3,'example_val2_col_3'),(2,'example_val2_col_2');` In this case example_val2_col_3 will be in the first row.

Comment: Aaron's solution only worked "by luck" in the specific sample data provided, unless more information is given. In addition notice that his solution pushes the null to end even if it should be in one of the rows above. More information is needed to understand what s the rules to have the values in the same row in the result set

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRJU4.png

Comment: my goal is that those rows would go in the order that they were loaded, so in order in which they were in the original file.
And my rule for giving ID'S in the first place was based on data in a given row. For example if beginning of this row value is 'X@' then it should have ID number 3.

Comment: Hi @LLawsford ,  

(1) A rowstore table is a SET of **Un-ordered** rows. In order to know the order which rows were inserted, you must have this information in the table. In your case, you don't have it. This is usually done by using the property IDENTITY or by using SEQUENCE or using rowversion (also known as timestamp).

When the server stores the data, the rows are not necessarily stored in the order which we inserted them! Same goes with reading the data using SELECT. The order of the rows in the result SET is not guaranteed unless you are using "ORDER BY'.

Comment: (2) Please provide queries to create your table and insert some sample data + the expected result set which you want to get from the sample data. This is the way to let us reproduce the scenario fast and have a discussion about the sample data - instead of what you provided which is text and description of the data. We simply need queries that we can execute and create the same sample table/data in our server `:-)`. Remember to add a column which represent the order which the rows were inserted, as I explained in point (1).

Comment: Off-topic: in any case, I would recommend you to think about re-design your database/system since storing the data like you do and without any relation between rows that are inserted at the same time and are part of the same "group" seems problematic. In first glance seems like you can gain performance by re-design your system (but to say this I would need to understand your full system so I can only guess/assume now).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to come up with a way to make sure each aggregate can only happen once. One way is to add a row number partitioning by `given_id`:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT given_id, data, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY given_id ORDER BY data)
  FROM dbo.example_table
)
SELECT [1],[2],[3]
  FROM x
  PIVOT (MIN(data) FOR given_id IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS p;
```

Though it may not be enough for me to test this with only 5 potential values.

- Example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c17098a36795c25553d5cd518affb480)